# Make a shapefile with geopandas from polygons

Tags: geopandas, tesselation

I am new in dealing with shapefiles. I have a dataset with points that represent centroids of polygons. I want to do a Voronoi tessellation and create a new shapefile with the obtained polygons arising from the tessellation. 
The code I wrote is the following:

```
import geopandas as gp
import numpy as np
import pytess

outfile = 'example.shp'

list_centroids = [[5602414.710853475, 2276953.868022472], [5602811.942643783, 2277014.42599593], [5602786.520959574, 2277078.203081659], [5602757.831566737, 2277135.13165023], [5602726.400724698, 2277190.140619183], [5602494.021571051, 2277170.492366924], [5602550.460524382, 2277207.810717136], [5602690.650712324, 2277265.214973784], [5602788.200198333, 2277290.096373509], [5602855.037044225, 2277326.977219126], [5603079.663762391, 2277456.471662892]]

points = np.array(lista_centroids)
voronoipolys = pytess.voronoi(points)
poligons = list()
for i in range(len(points)):
    centroid =  voronoipolys[i][0]
    pol = ''
    polygon = voronoipolys[i][1]
    #Here I create a string POLYGON ((x y),(x2 y2).. )) 
    for j in range(len(polygon)):
        if not j == len(polygon)-1:
            pol += str(polygon[j]).replace(',', '').replace('(','').replace(')','')+', '
        else:
            pol += str(polygon[j]).replace('(','').replace(')','')    .replace(',', '')
    pol = 'POLYGON (('+pol
    pol = pol+'))'
    poligons.append(pol)

df = gp.GeoDataFrame()
df['geometry'] = poligons
df.to_file(outfile,driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

But I cannot create the shapefile. I am sure I am making a mistake in the construction of the polygons or in assigning them to the dataframe. The error I get is

```
raise ValueError("Geometry column cannot contain mutiple "
ValueError: Geometry column cannot contain mutiple geometry types when writing to file.
```

Comment: "pol = 'POLIGON (('+pol" should be POLYGON in the WKT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of your script gives an incorrect wkt representation of the geometry.

```
for pol in poligons:
  print pol
POLIGON ((5602627.870219662 2276888.7486874633, 5600433.955237184 2274349.7263693763, 5602273.833740985 2277128.2769202497, 5602603.435908475 2277007.6026512305, 5602615.041954314 2276972.8960675565))
POLIGON ((5602627.870219662 2276888.7486874633, 5603213.399921105 2276729.95024462, 5603089.954983046 2277135.3403272615, 5603039.893437907 2277142.242787123, 5602615.041954314 2276972.8960675565))
POLIGON ((5602615.041954314 2276972.8960675565, 5603039.893437907 2277142.242787123, 5602912.429072924 2277177.348362445, 5602608.698603828 2277024.28210831, 5602603.435908475 2277007.6026512305))
POLIGON ((5602612.500504011 2277052.6463317936, 5602628.246582925 2277097.5737219886, 5602815.138219208 2277204.3592446083, 5602886.860059406 2277190.3038254376, 5602912.429072924 2277177.348362445, 5602608.698603828 2277024.28210831))
POLIGON ((5602637.937331706 2277194.0639783544, 5602747.445787883 2277246.2113285935, 5602815.138219208 2277204.3592446083, 5602628.246582925 2277097.5737219886))
POLIGON ((5602608.698603828 2277024.28210831, 5602612.500504011 2277052.6463317936, 5602292.044797937 2277537.292210747, 5602273.833740985 2277128.2769202497, 5602603.435908475 2277007.6026512305))
POLIGON ((5602628.246582925 2277097.5737219886, 5602637.937331706 2277194.0639783544, 5602515.341902792 2277493.461222109, 5602290.725913394 2277573.523150983, 5602292.044797937 2277537.292210747, 5602612.500504011 2277052.6463317936))
POLIGON ((5602747.445787883 2277246.2113285935, 5602687.732980731 2277480.320088962, 5602515.341902792 2277493.461222109, 5602637.937331706 2277194.0639783544))
POLIGON ((5602815.138219208 2277204.3592446083, 5602886.860059406 2277190.3038254376, 5602723.629402934 2277486.11651761, 5602687.732980731 2277480.320088962, 5602747.445787883 2277246.2113285935))
POLIGON ((5602912.429072924 2277177.348362445, 5603039.893437907 2277142.242787123, 5603089.954983046 2277135.3403272615, 5603097.727112216 2277165.567307192, 5602880.352628732 2277542.6345806415, 5602723.629402934 2277486.11651761, 5602886.860059406 2277190.3038254376))
POLIGON ((5603097.727112216 2277165.567307192, 5602880.352628732 2277542.6345806415))
```

But GeoPandas uses [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) for the geometries and not your geometric "construction". Therefore

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon
Polygon(voronoipolys[0][1]).wkt
'POLYGON ((5602627.870219662 2276888.748687463, 5600433.955237184 2274349.726369376, 5602273.833740985 2277128.27692025, 5602603.435908475 2277007.602651231, 5602615.041954314 2276972.896067556, 5602627.870219662 2276888.748687463))'
```

And the last polygon of your list with 2 points is clearly not a Polygon therefore

```
poligons = list()
for i in range(len(points)-1):
   polygon = Polygon(voronoipolys[i][1])
   poligons.append(polygon)
```

or with list comprehension

```
   poligons = [Polygon(voronoipolys[i][1]) for i in range(len(points)-1)]
```

Now create a simple GeoDatafame with the polygons

```
 poly_df = GeoDataFrame(geometry=poligons)
 poly_df.to_file(outfile,driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

[image]

You can do the same thing with LineStrings and Points

```
 points  = [Point(voronoipolys[i][0]) for i in (range(len(points))]
 lines = [LineString(voronoipolys[i][1])for i in (range(len(points))]


 lines_df = GeoDataFrame(geometry=lines)
 lines_df.to_file(outfile,driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

[image]

And with the points

[image]

You can also do the same thing with Shapely and [SciPy](https://www.scipy.org/) ([From Voronoi tessellation to Shapely polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27703081/835653))